# Getting twit npm package to work with meteor.js

Tags: api, http, twitter, meteor, npm

I am trying to pull in some tweets using the twit npm package and meteor.  I have installed meteorhacks:npm and http as dependencies, but am still having no luck.  Here is my code:

```js
/* server/lib/twitter-api.js */

Meteor.startup(function() {
  var Twit = Meteor.npmRequire('twit');

  Meteor.methods({
   'getStream': function() {
      var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: ['football']})
      stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
        console.log(tweet)
    })
      }
  });
});



/* private/twitter.js */

var T = new Twit(config) {
 consumer_key: "xxxxxxxx",
 consumer_secret: "xxxxxxx",
 app_only_auth: true
}



/* client/views/twitter/twitter.js */
Template.tweets.helpers({
 'streams': function() {
  return Session.get("streams");
 }
});

Template.tweets.events({
  'streams': function () {
    Meteor.call("getStream", function(error, res) {
   console.log(res);
   Session.set("tweet", res)
     });
    }
});
```

```html
<template name="tweets">
  <h1>Tweets</h1>
 {{ streams }}
</template>
```

Few things I am having trouble with: 
1) are my twit config keys stored in the correct path / correct format?
2) is my meteor method stored correctly?  Before i was getting an error saying it could not be found, but now my console says nothing at all
3) what do i need to do to get this work?  Right now it is attempting to pull in tweets tagged 'football'.  Is there an easier way to do this? Should I just used http.get and not the twit npm package?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use a twitter api package to expose the twit npm module I found the following it seems to be recent: https://atmospherejs.com/danimal/twit just to make life easier.

Also you need to remember that twit api will be Asynchronous because it's npm module. You need to convert the call to twitter api to be synchronous

That's the problem with your method it will return before it really gets anything

`var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: ['football']})`

we need to force it to wait for the result of the stream use http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync
 or
 https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-async

1. you can safely store it on the `server/` folder or even better http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_settings
2. You don't need to use `Meteor.startup` for meteor.methods
3. if you know Async/Sync just make it sync function, If you don't I suggest you to read more about it to really understand it, It will take some time, But basically the idea is we need to make it Sync so the server waits for the API result and only then return the meteor method call back with result of the API otherwise it will not wait and return you instantly undefined when you call the meteor method from client, Experiment with it add some console.log() and see how it handles itself.

How to make it work? Helper was fine but you be better call the meteor method on client like this + sync function on server side:

```
Template.tweets.onCreated(function() {
    Meteor.call("getStreams", function(error, res) {
      console.log(res);
      Session.set("streams", res)
    });
});
```